# How do I minimise any window using terminal commands?

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to make my discord bot console (**running in terminal**) minimize itself, but I do not know a command for minimizing. I tried looking around but I found nothing.

Comment: So you want to minimize a Terminal window? Does Cmd-H or Cmd-M not do what you want?

Comment: i need it to automaticly hide its self, like some sort of command that can be run to hide its self

Comment: What would trigger this?

Comment: a terminal command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command in shell script to minimize particular window of an open app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401431/command-in-shell-script-to-minimize-particular-window-of-an-open-app)

Comment: Want me to merge those answers here @Allan

Comment: We could, I guess @bmike

Comment: Not sure which direction is best TBH

Comment: My initial thought was to close this toward the one I linked since it had an answer where this didn’t though this is the older question.  I didn’t realize you could merge answers elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry i kind of blanked everyone here for a long time. Super sorry, allan posted a link to another thread which may or may not work, i am still yet to try it! Thanks allan if it works!